# React prevState parameter with map Function in setState

Tags: reactjs, dictionary, setstate

I am want to implement toggle functionality. (I have always used prevState to perform toggle operation) But in this case if I use prevState within map function. It is displaying error that "prevState is undefined".
I am posting 2 code, first one is working without prevState...but I want to implement it using prevState as shown in example enter code here2 (but 2nd code is giving the above mentioned error)

Correct:

```
  this.setState({
            rawData: this.state.rawData.map(a => {
                if(a.id === id){
                    a.completed = !a.completed
                }
                return a
            })
        })
```

example 2:

```
this.setState((prevState)=>{
            rawData: this.state.rawData.map(a => {
                if(a.id === id){
                    a.completed = !prevState.a.completed
                }
                return a
            })
        })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the mapping is incorrect from the second example because you aren't mapping from the `prevState`. `prevState.a` is likely what is `undefined`. You need to also shallow copy the element being updated, otherwise `a.completed = !a.completed` is considered a state mutation.

```
this.setState(prevState => ({
  rawData: prevState.rawData.map(a => {
    if (a.id === id) {
      return {
        ...a,
        completed: !a.completed,
      }
    }
    return a
  })
}))
```

Comment: I have used the following code to perform simple toggle operation. I have not added shallow copy of element. (I still work, here is the code)  ------------------                        handleClick = ()=>{
        this.setState((prevState)=>({
            isToggle : !prevState.isToggle
        }))
    }    ..........why is it so?

Comment: @UmerJaved Right, because there is no further nested state. With objects and arrays, simply copying the outer object/array to a new reference isn't enough if you updated nested state. Anything that is updated should be be a new object/array/value reference in order for react reconciliation to function correctly.

Comment: I am wondering how do you come up with this solution. I actually want to know if you were at my place and stuck in this problem, what do you do to find solution?  what will be your strategies?

Comment: The official docs are a great place to start. I've been in react development for about 3 years and still refer back to them. For the follow-on questions: [Using State Correctly](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#using-state-correctly) and [Setting State](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate) These primarily focus on the class-based component functions, but the react component lifecycle is the same for functional components.

Answer (score 0):

```
this.setState((prevState)=>({
    rawData: prevState.rawData.map(a => {
        if(a.id === id){
            a.completed = !a.completed
        }
        return a
    })
}))
```

Try this.

Comment: You should add more details as to why this solves the problem